# How to call a oracle procedure which deletes data using JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, stored-procedures, jdbc

My oracle procedure is like below which is used to remove the old users from DB.

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE                 UNAVAILABLE_USER (INACTIVE IN NUMBER DEFAULT 90) IS                                                                                                                                          CHK_ACTIVE_USER (NUMOFDAYS IN NUMBER DEFAULT 90) IS 
  //VARIABLE DECLARATIONS
BEGIN
LOOP
  //SOME LOGIC TO FIND WHICH USER ACCOUNTS TO BE DELETED
   END LOOP;
  LOOP
      DELETE FROM SCHEEMA.TABLE1 WHERE userid = ''id'';
      DELETE FROM SCHEEMA.TABLE2 WHERE userid = ''id'';
    END LOOP;
    COMMIT;
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    ROLLBACK;
END UNAVAILABLE_USER;
```

As far as oracle procedure is concerned its working fine and deleting data while checking in SQL developer. I need to execute that from java DAO layer.. i have been trying to execute the procedure like below..

```
connection = UserProfileDAO.getJDBCConnection();
CallableStatement statement = null;
String query = "CALL " + USER_SCHEMA + ".UNAVAILABLE_USER(?)";
statement = connection.prepareCall(query);
statement.setInt(1, Num_Off_Days);
statement.executeUpdate();
```

It is deploying and running fine, no issue from java side but deleting the data from db side

> 09:54:37,761 INFO  [com.alok.user.data.UserProfileDAO]
>   (pool-11-thread-1) inside the delete user   09:55:04,250 INFO 
>   [stdout] (pool-11-thread-1) CALL  USER_SCHEMA.UNAVAILABLE_USER(?)

Could you help me how to diagnose the issue and how this has been interacting with DB.. any other solution would be appreciable.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the connection in autoCommit mode ? If no, your code must do a commit after the delete: `connection.commit()`; Append this line at the end, it will work regardless of a state of autocommit.

Comment: Yes.. its in auto commit mode

Comment: Also I tried to make the auto commit mode as false before transaction.. that is also not working ..

Comment: Can you try removing the entire exception section from your procedure and executing it from Java. This way you will be certain that it is not running into any exception when executed from Java.

Comment: Does your app database user have the `DELETE` privilege?

Comment: Yes it has access.. certainly  using delete queries in other place also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have a problem with the JDBC syntax for calling stored procedures; you should surround the call string with *curly braces*. You could try something like this instead:

```
connection = UserProfileDAO.getJDBCConnection();
String call = "{ CALL " + USER_SCHEMA + ".UNAVAILABLE_USER(?) }";

try (CallableStatement statement = connection.prepareCall(call)) {
    statement.setInt(1, Num_Off_Days);
    statement.execute();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    // or throw something that can be handled 
    // by the code calling your DAO
    throw new RuntimeException(e); 
}
```

Things that have been changed include:

- The code is now using [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) so that the callable statement is properly closed even if an exception is thrown.
- Possible `SQLException`s that might be thrown when the statement is executed, are now logged and the exception doesn't go unnoticed

Comment: Yes.. i had kept all the mentioned code in try catch block.. There was a commit issue on my code. Transaction was not able to commit it was in autocommit mode and i was trying to commit again.
Thanks though for your solution .. it would also work..

Comment: @Alok, perhaps you could write up a short answer that describes the solution and mark it as accepted.